# Image display issue with googleusercontent

Tags: php, html, gmail

All of the images sent in gmail mails are changing by addition of googleusercontent at the beginning, example  http://static.abc.com/dir/images/mail/1.gif

will become

https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2RhhI8UCDUEhkF_Cgc1xToVBVxngHcgzoWYCNMbNruyVh8nTqxOnyL4ODpBLZC7_gq-De86bVHao8kcD8Rxeeusd2qXDleqIkJSRpSehJj9NUw=s0-d-e1-ft#http://static.abc.com/dir/images/mail/1.gif

Consequences :
As a result some of the images are not opening when i am opening the mail.
I have no idea what is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

GOOGLE is now re-writing image links within emails they receive. Images are now served via a proxy for all Gmail users.

So this means an image with the scr: site.com/image.jpg will be replaced by Gmail with a URL like https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/…#site.com/image.jpg